# Javascript bug "e.preventDefault();" is not a function

Tags: javascript

It's been an hour since I can not find where is my mistake. Moreover, I'm sure it's a stupid one. Anyway, here it's my javascript code :

```
var deleteRefsButton = document.getElementsByClassName('refs--item--delete');

var deleteRefs = function(e, i){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.parentNode.classList.add('deleted');
    document.getElementById('deletedInput'.i).value = true;
}

for (var i=0;i<deleteRefsButton.length;i++){
    var button = deleteRefsButton[i];
    button.addEventListener('click', deleteRefs(button,i), false);
}
```

And here my html scheme :

```
<div class="refs--item" id="refs1">
    <div class="refs--item--text">
        content
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="deleted1" value="false">
    <a class="refs--item--delete" href="#">Delete this refs</a>
</div>
<div class="refs--item" id="refs2">
    <div class="refs--item--text">
        content
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="deleted2" value="false">
    <a class="refs--item--delete" href="#">Delete this refs</a>
</div>
...
```

So, as you can see, my goal is to listen the click event on links (a.refs--item--delete), prevent the top scrolling, then add a "deleted" class to its parentNode and finally add the value true to the good hidden input.

But with this present code, nothing work, the console says :

```
 Uncaught TypeError: e.preventDefault is not a function
```

So maybe you saw my mistake.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What did you expect? You are passing `button` as the `e` parameter.

Comment: See this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25477317/typeerror-event-preventdefault-is-not-a-function Hope it helps.

Comment: Also, you’re not actually binding an event listener.

Comment: @Nimrod That has nothing to do with this question. He spelled it correctly.

Comment: Thanks @Oriol, I'm a bit tired (it's 03:20 am, in France) I will let javascript aside for know and will directly go to bed :D. Thanks to all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple things wrong that have to do with the fundamentals of javascript.

When using `addEventListener` you pass in the instance of the function you wish to trigger you don't execute it.

```
button.addEventListener('click', deleteRefs, false);
```

Then when the listener is triggered the event will be passed in as the first argument. That will solve `preventDefault` being undefined.

Second you are trying to do `getElementById('deletedInput'.i)` you are trying to call `i` on a String. That is not valid javascript. What you would do is:

```
getElementById('deletedInput' + i);
```

However `i` will be undefined because you cannot execute the function like you are doing in `addEventListener`.

I also want to note that doing this `document.getElementById('deletedInput'.i)` will not work because you have no elements with an ID prefixed with `deletedInput`. You can solve this with `querySelector`. I have added this to my example.

Finally I want to note that your for loop starts at 0. You have no elements with 0. You will need to add 1 to `i` when passing `i` your handler.

I have edited your code you could do something like this. If you have questions you can reference developer.mozilla.org. You could copy and paste this and it will work.

```
var deleteRefsButton = document.getElementsByClassName('refs--item--delete');
var deleteRefs = function(){

    // The arguments object is an Array-like object corresponding to the arguments passed to a function.
    var i = arguments[0];
    var e = arguments[1];
    e.preventDefault();
    e.currentTarget.parentNode.classList.add('deleted');
    document.querySelector('[name="deleted' + i + '"]').value = true;
}

for (var i=0; i < deleteRefsButton.length; i++){

    var button = deleteRefsButton[i];

    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind
    // .bind will prepend i the the list of arguments passed to deleteRefs
    button.addEventListener('click', deleteRefs.bind(this, i + 1), false);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your very pedagogical help. I'm a beginner in programmatic langages like javascript and php. I will examine patiently your solution to learn. (PS : For the concatenation mistake, it's because I switch from php to javascript)

Comment: Also I would like to note that it is better practice to use just one hyphen between words in your class names.